# How to unstage a modified file whose latest version is not staged

Tags: git

I have two files **a.txt** and **b.txt** which are in the working directory.
I have staged these files into the staging area using `git add .`.

[image]

Now I made some changes in b.txt file and didn't stage this file.

[image]

Now I want to unstage the b.txt (initial version) from staging area as I don't want to consider it for the commit. I haven't done any commit yet.

The output of `git status` tells me to use `git rm --cached b.txt` but this isn't working in this case. I want to know why is it not working and how to achieve this? It works when the file is in same state in both the working and staging area.

Comment: you use `git reset` to get a file out of the index..... or rather, to get it back to what it was in `HEAD` (a.k.a. _the current commit that you are on_).... if it's like the first commit in the project, then it will just remove it from index.

Comment: Do not post pictures of text. Post TEXT

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean when you use `git rm --cached b.txt`?

Comment: It gives below error when i run ```git rm --cached b.txt``` in given scenario [```git reset filename``` is working for such requirement though]:

error: the following file has staged content different from both the
file and the HEAD:
    b.txt
(use -f to force removal)

Comment: You are running a very old version of git if your status output looks like that. Please update.

Comment: I am using git 2.44.0 version which is the latest

Comment: What's wrong with just doing what it tells you to do? You changed the file's content after adding it, so `git reset` is going to lose the index pointer to content you probably don't have another copy of, if you really want to do that add `-f` / `--force` as a reset option, a "yes I know that content's not what anyone else has, reset it anyway".

Answer (score 3):

It is not entirely clear what the problem / goal is here, but it evidently has something to do with wanting to modify the state of a certain file in the Git index. So, in line with the philosophy that it's better to teach you to fish than to just give you a fish, I'll describe more about what your options are and let you take it from there.

To understand the situation, it will help to know more clearly what a commit is and what the index is.

- The most recent commit, also known as `HEAD`, is a *complete* snapshot of the *entire* state of your project at the time the commit was made.
- The index is *also* a *complete* snapshot of the *entire* state of your project. It starts life matching `HEAD`, but then you say `git add` (or similar) and this causes a change in the state of one or more of the files in the index. The purpose here is to collect a snapshot of your project which will be used the *next* time you say `git commit`.
- The working tree is the place where you actually edit files. You may think of this as your project, but that's not actually what it is. It is *another* snapshot of the *entire* state of your project, which has the special property that it looks like a normal file tree and that you can edit its files directly. Its purpose, as far as Git is concerned, is so that you can prepare files for adding to the index.

So what you will do now depends on what state of *b.txt* you want in the index, i.e. what state of *b.txt* you want to use *the next time you make a commit*.

- If you want the state of *b.txt* in the index to look like the working tree version of *b.txt* does now, you say

  ```
  git add b.txt
  ```
- If you want the state of *b.txt* in the index to look like the `HEAD` version of *b.txt* does now, you say

  ```
  git restore --staged b.txt
  ```
- If you want the state of *b.txt* in the index to look like it does already, do nothing.

Finally, if (in order to make an intelligent decision) you would like to *see* the three states of *b.txt*, here's how:

- To see the state of *b.txt* in `HEAD`, say

  ```
  git show HEAD:b.txt
  ```
- To see the state of *b.txt* in the index, say

  ```
  git show :b.txt
  ```
- To see the state of *b.txt* in the working tree, say

  ```
  cat b.txt
  ```

Another way to inspect the situation is in terms of diffs:

- To see the difference between the index and the working tree states of *b.txt*, say

  ```
  git diff -- b.txt
  ```
- To see the difference between the `HEAD` and the working tree states of *b.txt*, say

  ```
  git diff HEAD -- b.txt
  ```
- To see the difference between the `HEAD` and the working tree states of *b.txt*, say

  ```
  git diff --staged -- b.txt
  ```